# Rails 3, using UJS on html area tag

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

When the user clicks on on area of an image I want to trigger and ajax request to the server. Is there an easy way to implement this a-la Rails 3 UJS? Something similar to link_to ..., :remote=>true?

I have tried to the following code:

```
#post_bar
  =image_tag 'post_bar_270x57.png', :usemap=>'#add_post'
  %map{:name=>"add_post"}
    %area{:shape=>"rect", :coords=>"40,4,86,50", :href=>new_message_path, :'data-remote'=>'true', :title=>"Message"}
```

but the added data-remote attributes does not work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several things I concluded the easiest way is to to have an HTML anchor element on top of the png with that I can simply use the link_to helper with :remote=>true.
It took me less than 10 minutes to get the all thing working.

Edit: here is the code form my haml file (in production I removed the map element)

```
#post_bar
  =image_tag 'post_bar_270x57.png', :usemap=>'#add_post'
  %map{:name=>"add_post"}
    %area{:shape=>"rect", :coords=>"40,4,86,50", :href=>new_message_path, :title=>"Message"}
    %area{:shape=>"rect", :coords=>"100,4,146,50", :href=>new_message_path, :title=>"Reminder(140 chars)"}
  #post_message_link
    =link_to "", new_message_path, :remote=>true
```

and the css

```
#post_message_link a{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 40px;
    width: 45px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm tried your suggestion by adding an anchor around image for the map but it doesn't seem to work. In your setup, do you have each area with its own href? If so then then what href do you use for the anchor around the image? Can you post your code in a pastie?

Answer (score 0):

In the jquery-rails gem (path found with 'bundle show jquery-rails') there is a javascript file for jquery-ujs under vendor/assets/javascripts.

On line 51 you can see the following:

```
// Link elements bound by jquery-ujs   
linkClickSelector: 'a[data-confirm], a[data-method], a[data-remote], a[data-disable-with]'
```

I found adding the area tag to this line allows you to use UJS in the same way as you do for normal links, etc.

Ideally, you would make the code a bit better by adding another variable, but since this is just a hack I added it to the existing variables.

```
// Link elements bound by jquery-ujs   
linkClickSelector: 'a[data-confirm], a[data-method], a[data-remote], a[data-disable-with]', 'area[data-confirm]', 'area[data-method]', 'area[data-remote]',
```